# OpenCV: How to compute the mean of a Grayscale and save the output to a txt-file

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I am using the openCV library in python. I have read in a video and marked a Region of Interest in it. I have converted the frame from BGR to Grayscale and within the ROI I am taking a threshold on value 60. What I want to do now is: Compute the mean of the intensity values within the ROI. Do this for every frame of the video. And then write the result to a txt-file.

Here is my idea:

```
ROI_intensity = str(cv2.mean(thresh))
file = open("VelocityAnalysis.txt", "a+")
file.write(ROI_intensity)
file.close()
```

This, however, doesn't yield the intended result: `str(cv2.mean(thresh))` returns a tuple with 4 (!) entries, while I was expecting just one. This is probably related to the three color channels and some last parameter, which I don't know, what it is there for. Possible fix

```
help = str(cv2.mean(thresh))
ROI_intensity = help[0]
```

This doesn't look nice to me, however. Is there a better solution?

The other problem with this code is that I want each result to be printed on its own row. And - this is probably the hardest part for me - I want to have a time next to the intensity value. The video has been taken with a framerate of 30 fps. So I should be able to have knowledge about the video time of each frame. I could simply create a count variable and assume that with every frame the count goes up by 1/30 seconds. But, again, is there a more sophisticated solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the first problem, you are right. The tuple of 4 represents the mean of 4 channels, R G B and alpha respectively, where alpha denotes transparency (Note that this depends on how you read the image. RGBA or BGRA). So writing `help[0]` is basically writing the mean value of first channel.

Regarding the second question, if you have the knowledge of the time video started getting recorded, you can get a timestamp like this,

```
timestamp_of_recorded_video = 0
fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
frame_count = 0
while (True) :
     frame, ret = video.read()
     frame_count = frame_count + 1
     current_time_stamp = timestamp_of_recorded_video + (frame_count/fps) #Convert to datetime format as per your convenience
     file.write(str(current_time_stamp) + ',' + str(ROI_intensity) + '\n')
```

This is for OpenCV3. Use datetime library of Python add time stamps.